# How to handle HTML <forms> with javascript

Tags: javascript, forms

i'm studying javascript but i can't find some clear reference about how getting and treat data out of the HTML forms.

Here an example:

THE FORM:

```
<HTML>
              <HEAD>

<TITLE>Database Lookup</TITLE> 
<script src="basic.js"></script></HEAD>
<BODY>
<H1>Database Lookup</H1>
<FORM  action="javascript: submitForm();">
Please enter the ID of the publisher you want to find: <BR>
<INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="id">
<BR>
<INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" value="Submit" > </FORM>
          </BODY>
     <HTML>

    //HERE JAVASCRIPT Javascript BASIC.js:

function submitForm() 
{

var idsearched=document.getElementById("id").innerHTML;
document.write("idsearched");
}
```

I would like to know what i'm doing wrong, because nothing happen when i click submit. And which is the better solution for handling forms with javascript?? Using "action"? or which of other attributes?

Comment: var idsearched=document.getElementById("id").value;document.write(idsearched);

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp

Comment: I don't see any element with `id="id"`, just `NAME="id"`.

Comment: You say that nothing happens when you click submit, but what do you expect to happen? Specifically, if you do `document.write` from within a .js file, where do you think its output will end up? Also, the second `<html>` tag needs to be an end tag.

Comment: ty to all. Sergio you were right, stupid stupid mistake... it make me think that the error was at the base of my little knowledge... searching the internet i find a lot of different ways for handling form with js so i wanted to know why mine didn't work. @MrLister i didn't notice the end tag.. about the  "document.write" i expected to overwrite all the content of the page with my form's input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of form elements are contained in their value attribute. Try the modified code snippet below.
**Note:** `("idsearched")` should be without quote because it is a variable and not a string.

```
var idsearched=document.getElementById("id").value;
document.write(idsearched);
```

You must add an id attribute to the form element.

```
<INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="id" id="id">
```

Use this line to manually submit your form

```
<INPUT TYPE="button" value="Submit" onclick="submitForm();" >
```

Answer (score 1):

`<INPUT TYPE="button" value="Submit" onclick="submitForm();" >`

do not use `document.write` use `document.getElementById("myID").innerHTML`

Comment: yw, anyway you should look into jquery, it makes these kinda things alot easier, this is pretty much what its made for.

Comment: i know, i tried that last day and it is amazing! But i need to learn some js for the university! :( TY again!

Comment: well ye, knowing js helps, it gives you more understanding of whats going on, but jquery should be the bulk of your coding.(client-side scripting)

Answer (score 0):

a full working example like you wanted is that:

```
<HTML>
   <HEAD>
      <TITLE>Database Lookup</TITLE>
      <script src="basic.js"></script>
   </HEAD>
   <BODY>
      <H1>Database Lookup</H1>
      <FORM  action="javascript: submitForm();">
         Please enter the ID of the publisher you want to find: <BR>
         <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" id="id" NAME="id">
         <BR>
         <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" value="Submit" > 
      </FORM>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         function submitForm() 
         {

         var idsearched=document.getElementById("id").innerHTML;
         document.write("idsearched");
         return false;
         }
      </script>
   </BODY>
   <HTML>
```